# Password recovery using SMS with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to implement password recovery on Android using SMS to mobile phone using `Firebase`. But now I can find only password recovery using email([Send a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email)). So, how can I implement this feature but using SMS and mobile phone number using `Firebase`? Or what workaround I can implement if there is no way to do it using default `Firebase` methods(preferably using some other `Firebase` methods)?

Comment: How would this flow work? Are you planning to link a phone number to a password account? You would need to map an email to a phone number. Also are you planning to send a reset link in an SMS?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a bad workaround since we don't have a "Password recovery with SMS" in Firebase.

Step 1: Authenticate the user with Phone number.
Step 2: Delete the user and save the UserId.
Step 3: Create new user with same email Id.
Step 4: This will generate a new user with different UserId. Replace the old UserId whereever stored with the new one.

Hope it works..!